# Translation not working after editing plugin template

Tags: themes, translation

I'm building a website with Wordpress and I'm using the plugin Event Organiser.

I changed the config file of Wordpress to use the nl_NL (Dutch) language. This all works fine, even for the plugin, except the pages that use a template I overloaded in my child theme.

So I made this child theme for twenty eleven, and I copied a template file of the plugin and put it in my child theme and edited it there.

Now only a part is translated to Dutch, the English words/sentences that come after the edited parts (that normally are translated) stay in English.

For instance I see this line in my template:

```
<?php edit_post_link( __( 'Edit'), '<span class="edit-link">', '</span>' ); ?>
```

or this line:

```
$utility_text = __( 'This event was posted by <a href="%5$s">%4$s</a>.', 'eventorganiser' );
```

which then gets printed with `printf`. I did not add these lines, they were already in the template, and did work when the template was unaltered.

What can I do to fix this? Even the edit button, which translate to dutch on other pages, doesn't translate.

A one line solution would be great.. But that won't be the case sadly :D

Answer (score 0):

You could try to run poedit on the plugin to see if there are untranslated strings, but it seems related to the use of child-theme template file.

Maybe a quick fix could be to copy the lang files into your child theme folder too and see if it works (you will probably need to change de text_domain for each strings and generate a new lang file for your needs).

I'm not very familiar with child themes and plugin template files, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Check the plugin translation files. If they aren't there or are not complete, then there won't happen a translation.

When you see a [textdomain](http://codex.wordpress.org/I18n_for_WordPress_Developers), then this string belongs to this textdomain. If you see none, then it's the global WordPress core translation file.

So `__('Edit');` will be translated by core and `__( 'This event was posted by <a href="%5$s">%4$s</a>.', 'eventorganiser' );` by @StephenHarris "Event Organiser" plugin. If the plugin [has a translation file for `nl_NL`](http://plugins.svn.wordpress.org/event-organiser/trunk/languages/), then it *might* have this string translated. But at the end this depends on the translator (a living person). You can anytime jump in and add/edit such files and send them to the author.